# The consumer isn't authorized to access %resources "resources": "Magento_Sales::actions_view"

Tags: magento2.4.6

In a magento 2.4.6 installation I have created the below api.xml which has created a new integration which I activated.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<integrations xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Integration:etc/integration/api.xsd">
    <integration name="Test">
        <resources>
            <resource name="Magento_Sales::sales"/>
            <resource name="Magento_Sales::sales_operation"/>
            <resource name="Magento_Sales::actions"/>
            <resource name="Magento_Sales::sales_order"/>    
            <resource name="Magento_Sales::actions_view"/>
        </resources>
    </integration>
</integrations>
```

When I try to GET to /rest/V1/orders with the access token I get subject error

Many thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Did you check in `Stores > Configuration > Services > OAuth > Consumer Settings` if `Allow OAuth Access Tokens to be used as standalone Bearer tokens` is set to yes?[image]